How do I avoid whitespace collapsing in Motion Canvas Text?
I am recently using Motion Canvas for my animations. I want to avoid whitespace collapsing in Txt component. I have looked for solution like change the style of whitespace to pre but this is not even an option. This is what I want to do.
interface TextNodeProps {
    text: string;
    color: string;
}

interface ColorNodeProps {
    text: string;
}


const Red = ({text}: ColorNodeProps) => <TextNode text={text} color='#ff0000'/>

const Green = ({text}: ColorNodeProps) => <TextNode text={text} color='#00ff00'/>

const TextNode = ({text, color}: TextNodeProps) => <Txt text={text} fill={color}/> 

When I use like this
<Red text='Hello    World'/>

It only renders
Hello World

*whitespace collapsed
Rather I want this
Hello    world

Any help is appreciated.

I have found a way to do this. There is some property called textWrap which I can set to ‘pre’ to stop collapsing whitespaces. But I don't know whether it is bug or what. My text is “ Hello“ but it displays “ Hello “. Whole spaces are shifted some how.
